# Change in entropy of an iron bar

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy

A small iron bar of mass $M = 1kg$ at temperature $1000 K$ is put in a lac at temperature $288 K$. Given that the thermic capacity of the iron bar is $440 J \cdot kg^{-1} \cdot K^{-1}$ I need to calculate the difference $\Delta S$ of entropy of the iron bar. (we suppose that the iron bar has constant volume).

So after some time the iron bar will be at temperature $288 K$, thus $\Delta S$ is negative. The heat gives an energy of $10^3 \cdot 440 J$ at the iron bar, so the heat transfer from the lac to iron bar is $(288-10^3) \cdot 440 J$.

So I found that : $\Delta S = \frac{-712 \cdot 440}{288}$ yet it seems that this is false... Where am I wrong ?

Thank you !

Comment: The change in entropy is the integral of dq/T only for a reversible path.  You have calculated the integral of dq/T for an irreversible path.  You need to identify an alternate reversible process path and calculate the integral for that path.  This alternate path will involve more than just heat transfer to a single heat sink (reservoir).   Can you think of an alternate reversible path?

Comment: @ChetMiller The OP did not compute the integral.

Comment: @Pieter What he did was mathematically equivalent to computing the integral.

Comment: $\Delta S = mc_pln(T_2/T_1)$ for an incompressible solid, assuming constant specific heat.